# How to prompt user for input again using do-while loops

Tags: java, do-while

I am trying to prompt the user if she wants to do a conversion again. I am using a do while loop statement and this is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FinalTemp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declare the variables
        float temperature = 0;
        boolean number;

        //The condition is check before running
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Farenheit number:");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (input.hasNextFloat())
            {
                temperature = input.nextFloat();
                number = true;
                temperature = ((temperature - 32)*5)/9;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                number = false;
                input.next();   
            }

        } while (!(number));//means not equal to the variable number
        System.out.println("Celcius is " + temperature);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code ends in the middle so it is not clear where exactly you have you problems. Would something like following work for you?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean stop = false;

    // outer loop for two questions
    do {
        //Declare the variables
        float temperature = 0;
        boolean number;

        // The loop for conversion question
        //The condition is check before running
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Farenheit number:");
            if (input.hasNextFloat()) {
                temperature = input.nextFloat();
                number = true;
                temperature = ((temperature - 32) * 5) / 9;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                number = false;
                input.next();
            }

        } while (!(number));//means not equal to the variable number
        System.out.println("Celcius is " + temperature);

        // The loop for "one more?"
        do {
            System.out.println("Do you want to convert one more? (Y/N)");
            String yesNo = input.next();

            boolean yes = yesNo.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'y';
            boolean no = yesNo.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'n';

            if (yes) {
                stop = false;
                break;
            } else if (no) {
                stop = true;
                break;
            } else
                System.out.println("Only Y or N is expected.");
        }
        while (true);
    }
    while (!stop);
}
```